# how to enable datalabels for bullet chart in sap ui5?

Tags: sapui5

I am using a horizontal bullet chart for one of my sap ui5 application.
Even after setting the data label visible property to true, the datalabels are not showing up on graph

```
dataLabel: {
             formatString: formatNumberString,
             visible: true,
             showTotal: true,
             unitFormatType:"FinancialUnits",
             hideWhenOverlap:false,
             style:{
               fontSize:"11px",
               fontWeight:"bold"
             },
}
```

Comment: Please take your time to write your question. Give us some code and provided it in the correct style. It makes it way easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this in the onInit function.

```
var idChart = this.getView().byId("idChart");
            idChart.setVizProperties({
                plotArea: {
                    dataLabel: {
                        visible: true
                    }
                }
            });
```